# Unable to install cordova-plugin-mfp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am trying to integrate IBM MobileFirst 8 into a fresh Ionic 3 / Cordova 7 based project by installing cordova-plugin-mfp. However it failed with message

```
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-plugman version. cordova-plugman: 7.0.1, failed version requirement: >=6.1.1 <7
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-mfp' for android
```

Appreciate if anyone can advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an older version of Cordova. Cordova 7 is not yet supported by cordova-plugin-mfp.

Answer (score 1):

"Use an older version of Cordova. Cordova 7 is not yet supported by cordova-plugin-mfp."

When will this be updated?
[Terminal screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv33U.png)